# Adding google fonts (fonts.googleapis.com) to CSP header

Tags: html, meta, content-security-policy

I am hosting a personal project on gitHub pages, and using cloudflare to enforce https. Now I would like to implement a CSP policy.

I tried adding meta tag to the head of my page:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Security-Policy' CONTENT="default-src 'self' *.fonts.googleapis.com/* *.cloudflare.com/* *.fonts.googleapis.com/*;">
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self' *.fonts.googleapis.com/* *.cloudflare.com/*
>   *.fonts.googleapis.com/*". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

This are the scripts that I am including:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
        rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

won't setting `*.fonts.googleapis.com/*` allow everything from the page?

Since this is the first time I am setting a CSP is this the correct way to set it for github pages? I have not found any reading on this yet.

Comment: I am experiencing this same error from Chrome on a dotnet core MVC application.

Comment: @WilliamLohan setting it to CONTENT="default-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com fonts.gstatic.com cloudflare.com; Executable scripts still won't work though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Won't setting *.fonts.googleapis.com/* allow everything from the page?

Although this would be intuitive, the answer is **no**.

See the pretty good [HTML5rocks introduction to Content Security Policy](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) on the topic of wildcards (section [Implementation details](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#implementation-details)):

> Wildcards are accepted, but only as a scheme, a port, or in the leftmost position of the hostname: *://*.example.com:* would match all subdomains of example.com (**but not example.com itself**), using any scheme, on any port.

So a working CSP for the two fonts could look something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ 'unsafe-inline';">
```

---

Note 1: It's a good practice to use the corresponding [CSP directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Directives). In your case you should use the `font-src` and `style-src` like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline';">
```

The advantage of using the corresponding directives is that your CSP gets pretty restrictive now. E.g., you're not allowing `'unsafe-inline'` for script sources anymore. This means inline javascript is now forbidden. It's also forbidden to load scripts from  https://fonts.gstatic.com/, which was allowed before. And so on...

---

Note 2: You can get rid of the `'unsafe-inline'` keyword at all by using a hash or a nonce. I have not been able to make this work for this example but if you're interested, just take a look at the [HTML5rocks intro](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#if-you-absolutely-must-use-it) again.

Comment: Still a solution on 17 Nov 2020!