# Google fonts not loading despite security policy setting

Tags: html, meta-tags, content-security-policy, google-font-api

I want to load fonts from google, but it doesn't work, tried different variations of Content-Security-Policy, but it continues to fail. With the configuration below, I'm getting:

> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Does this error even make sense? I'm setting the style-src property.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/materialize/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

Comment: post your CSP config, please

Comment: I did... <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;">

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369075/adding-google-fonts-fonts-googleapis-com-to-csp-header

Comment: Thank you @Ali, it makes sense, but it didn't work, still getting the same error: "because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

Comment: Alright, found it. The header is been overwritten by custom code in the application. I'm sorry I didn't find it sooner. Anyone going off the IdentityServer4 example might come across this issue.